# How to use Google's auto complete places api in Android application

Tags: android, google-places-api

I want to use Google Places API in my android application. I have API Key I got it from Google's API console. I am following the *Perform Autocomplete* section in [this tutorial](http://ddewaele.blogspot.in/2011/05/introducing-google-places-api.html).

Now the problem I am facing is exactly which jar file I need for this. I have tried with two:

1. `google-api-client-1.6.0-beta.jar`

   In this case I am getting exception when creating the object of class where I have implemented these methods and imported the packages of above library
2. `google-http-client-1.6.0-beta.jar`

   GoogleHeaders cannot be resolved to a type

If I comment the code where I am setting header to request it does not shows any error but
when I execute the code I get the following error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions

I have also added all the dependency jars.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use a specific client. Just use any library that can make HTTP requests (like Apache HttpClient), then parse the JSON (or XML) that you get back from the Places API.